# 2.5 kV Low Frequency Switching Circuit

Tags: high-voltage, switching

I am working on designing a circuit to generate and switch a 2.5kV and -2.5kV power supply to generate a high voltage square wave. The intent is to generate an electrostatic field between two conductors, so power draw requirements are small.

A simplified circuit with switches is shown.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk4RCx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have already figured out the best way to generate the high voltages (cap-diode multiplier due to space constraints), but switching the voltages has proven challenging. Is there some resource for high voltage switching I should look into, or some typical way to do this?

I was looking at high voltage reed relays, but they get quite expensive.

**ETA:**  @Tony Stewart EE75 Made the good point about not having a load or switching time defined in the problem.

- Switching time: <500us
- Load type: capacitive
- Load value: 5 pF

Comment: The long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it has been moved to chat and should be continued there (link below). --- As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once, any further comments posted here which try to clarify and understand the question, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post an answer, then please do that. As usual, any updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127512/discussion-on-question-by-g-rizzles-2-5-kv-low-frequency-switching-circuit).